# How to continue program execution after an exception is thrown in AWS SDK PHP?

Tags: php, aws-sdk

I'm checking for a file on the S3 bucket:

```
try {
    $result = $this->s3->headObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $this->bucket,
        'Key' => "$location"    
    ));     
 } catch(S3 $e) {
      error_log( $e->getMessage() );
 }
```

However program execution stops when the error is thrown, "S3Exception thrown

Error executing "HeadObject", AWS HTTP error: Client error: `...` resulted in a `404 Not Found`"

Any ideas on how to prevent it from stopping?

Comment: Catch `S3Exception`, not `S3`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: agreed, the name of the exception class is `S3Exception`, not just `S3`. You have to give the exact name of the class, and then it will catch all of exceptions of that class type (and any classes which inherit from it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to catch the execution, as Sammitch pointed out, is with S3Exception:

```
try {
    $result = $this->s3->headObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $this->bucket,
        'Key' => "$location"    
    ));     
 } catch(S3Exception $e) {
      error_log( $e->getMessage() );
 }
```